# Data mappers in Presentation layer

Tags: android, clean-architecture

I have been developing an android application using Clean Architecture and I am reading that it is a good practice to use different objects for each layer. But, I am doing this in my application and i am not sure If I should make entities for each layer (data, domain and presentation) and a mapper for each one.

I always had been using mapper and entities for data layer and "mapping" these objects to java objects in domain layer and passing these objects to presentation, so what is the best way to do this? I mean, what is the best practice to use in Clean architecture and following the data flow from data layer (getting data from API, for example) and finally showing this data in UI.

Thanks!

Comment: You should study about DTO concept in clean architecture. Basically you don't need to write mapper instead this responsibility should be handed over to DTO which will transform models from one layer to another.

Comment: Regarding whether to add entities in each layer or not. This really depends on variation of data that you want to use. e.g the model you fetched from server is different from what you need to use for business logic, which commonly does. so you will write separate model in both layer, same goes for the case of presentation. There is no hard and fast rule for that.